# How do I tell playframework to use my corporate proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, playframework

I'm trying to get started with the play web framework and its scala support,

unfortunately "install scala" fails because play can't fetch the module site.

I've got my system settings correct for the corporate proxy, however play doesn't seem to use them.

Is there a config file somewhere or some environment properties I need to set for play to pick them up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that it's only working with 1.1.1 which isn't released yet. See [bug 210](http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/210-play-command-list-modules-ignores-http_proxy). I'm unsure but I think list-modules and install are use the same code to get the proxy.
You can install it manually.

Answer (score 5):

The install command, implemented in Python, uses ulrlib behind the scenes: https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/framework/pym/play/commands/modulesrepo.py#L73

The `urllib` library allows setting a proxy via the ENV var `http_proxy`: http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#high-level-interface

So, you might try setting a proxy through that ENV variable.

Comment: gave it a shot but no go, thanks for the pointers though, the python library claims that MaxOSX should try to retrieve it from the OS settings, so not sure why it's not working...  I wonder if there's any way to get some more output so I can tell what it's doing

Comment: I ran into this issue with verion 1.2.1. on Windows XP Setting the HTTP_PROXY env variable to http://<yourproxy>:<port> did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

are you sure that the modules location is not blocked by the proxy? Are you able to access the URL via your browser, or if you are running on Linux, using wget?

URL you want is http://www.playframework.org/modules/scala-head.zip.

If you can access it, you can simply download the file and unzip into the play modules directly. That is all the install command does anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend using software such as Proxifier to deal with corporate proxy servers, not dealing with it on the application level.  That will allow you to control all of your proxy configuration in one place, and will also work much more seamlessly than trying to update individual software packages.

http://www.proxifier.com/

If you are on U*nx, try CNTLM instead.

http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/